# Is it possible to add Google Analytics to doxygen generated files?

Tags: api, google-analytics, analytics, doxygen

Is it possible to add Google Analytics to the HTML files generated by [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) dynamically (e.g. in the Doxyfile) at the time they are auto-created?  Can someone give an example of how this could be done from within the GUI or from within the Doxyfile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the same HTML code needs to be added to each of the generated HTML files, you could replace Doxygen header using the `HTML_HEADER` option on the Doxyfile:

```
HTML_HEADER= = header.html
```

Doxygen can generate an initial header.html using the following command:

```
doxygen -w html <header> <footer> <stylesheet>
```

Where `<header>`, `<footer>` and `<stylesheet>` are the filenames that should be generated for the respective components.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed....except I discovered that I actually needed HTML_FOOTER...but since they both work the same way you deserved the upvote.